# How can I compare 3 files together (to see what is in common between them)?

Tags: linux, comparison, awk, wc

I want to compare 3 files together to see how much of the information in the files are the same. The file format is something like this:

```
Chr11   447     .       A       C       74      .       DP=22;AF1=1;CI95=1,1;DP4=0,0,9,8;MQ=15;FQ=-78   GT:PL:GQ        1/1:107,51,0:99
Chr10   449     .       G       C       35      .       DP=26;AF1=0.5;CI95=0.5,0.5;DP4=5,0,7,8;MQ=20;FQ=11.3;PV4=0.055,0.0083,0.028,1   GT:PL:GQ        0/1:65,0,38:41
Chr12   517     .       G       A       222     .       DP=122;AF1=1;CI95=1,1;DP4=0,0,77,40;MQ=23;FQ=-282       GT:PL:GQ        1/1:255,255,0:99
Chr10   761     .       G       A       41      .       DP=93;AF1=0.5;CI95=0.5,0.5;DP4=11,34,6,35;MQ=19;FQ=44;PV4=0.29,1.8e-35,1,1      GT:PL:GQ        0/1:71,0,116:74
```

I'm only interested in the first two columns (if the first two columns are the same then I consider it as equal). This is the comand that I use for comparing two files :

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1] {pair[$1 " " $2]; next} ($1 " " $2 in pair)'  file1 file2 | wc -l
```

I would like to use the awk command since my files are really big and awk handle them really good! but I couldn't figure out how to use it for 3 files!

Comment: How would you like to present the common lines? Print them out all out? or just print the first 2 columns?

Comment: all out would be much better!

Comment: so for an entry where the first 2 columns are the same but the other columns are different in each file you want all 3 lines printed?

Comment: also, for each file, is it safe to assume that column1-column2 pair is unique?

Comment: the thing is that I need this for two purpose first I want to know how many of them is similar! so it doesn't matter if only the first two columns will be used! but for the second purpose I would like to have all the information if possible in one line (all the three lines will be printed in one line or something like that) what I don't want is to have 3 line for one position!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right but if you mean that in one file there is only one position with column one and two (e.g. there is only one position "chr11 447" in the file) then the answer is yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's simply to print out the pairs (column1 + column2) that are common in all 3 files, and making use of the fact that a pair is unique within a file, you could do it this way:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2}' a b c | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1==3){print $2" "$3}}'
```

This can be made with arbitrary numbers of files as long as you modify the param of the last command.

Here's what it does:

1. prints and sorts the first 2 columns of all files (`awk '{print $1" "$2}' a b c | sort`)
2. count the number of duplicate entries (`uniq -c`)
3. if duplicate entry count == number of files, we found a match. print it.

If you're doing this often, you can express it as a bash function (and drop it in your `.bashrc`) which parametrises the file counts.

```
function common_pairs { 
    awk '{print $1" "$2}' $@ | sort | uniq -c | awk -v numf=$# '{if ($1==numf){print $2" "$3}}'; 
}
```

Call it with any number of files you want: `common_pairs file1 file2 file3 fileN`

Answer (score 4):

Not intended to start an editor war, but I am familiar with VI, and vimdiff and its variants show the comparison between multiple files in parallel view, which I find very handy. Simply you can call it with

```
$ vimdiff <filelist>
```

Answer (score 3):

For this I'd use the commands *cut*, *sort* and *comm*.

1. With *cut* cut away the fields not needed.
2. *sort* the outcome since *comm* expects sorted input.
3. Use *comm* to get the lines which are in file1 and file2.
4. Use *comm* again to get the lines that are also in file3.

A script could look like this:

```
 for i in 1 2 3
  do
   # options to cut may have to be adjusted for your input files
   cut -c1-15 file$i | sort > tmp.$i
  done

 comm -12 tmp.1 tmp.2   > tmp.1+2
 comm -12 tmp.3 tmp.1+2 > tmp.1+2+3
```

*(Of course one may use extended shell syntax to avoid temporary files, but I don't want to hide the idea behind complex syntax expressions)*

In file `tmp.1+2+3` you now should have the keys present in all three files. If you're interested in the whole lines, you may use the command *join* in combination with a sorted version of any of the thee input files)

Comment: This can also be expressed as `comm -12 <(awk '{print $1" "$2}' a|sort) <(awk '{print $1" "$2}' b|sort) | comm -12 - <(awk '{print $1" "$2}' c|sort)`

Comment: Yes, but tedious to parse for a beginner - that's why I don't have used this syntax

Answer (score 3):

Just read your last comment - You want the files joined, but duplicates removed?

```
 sort file1 file2 file3 | uniq > newfile
```

Comment: Or simply `sort -u file1 file2 file3`, but that's not what the OP is asking for I believe.