# How can I compare 3 files together (to see what is unique in one file)?

Tags: unix, awk

I have three files file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt and they are of same format.

I want to select records from file1.txt which are not present in file2.txt, file3.txt based on col2, col3. Could you please advise me how to do this ?

I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964807/how-can-i-compare-3-files-together-to-see-what-is-in-common-between-them) where they described on comparing two files for common records and understood that this can be done using awk.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '(x=ARGIND==3)&&!a[$2,$3];!x{a[$2,$3]++}' file{3,2,1}
```

Comment: JID, 
Thank you. 
I am new to the unix environment. It would be of great help, if you could explain me the beautiful solution you have recommended?